# change color from id with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am changing the background colors from specific id's. At the moment I only have this `$(this).css('background-color','red')` to change the color. I was wondering if there are any other possibilities?

This is the full script. I Hope u can help me.

```js
$("#tabel td").each(function() {
  var cellValue = $(this).html();
  if (!isNaN(parseFloat(cellValue))) {
    if (cellValue > 0) {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    if (cellValue == 0) {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? It seems fine in isolation. It's not clear what the purpose of the question is.

Comment: You could use css classes instead of `$(..).css(..)`, eg `.hasvalue { color: red; }` and `$(this).addClass("hasvalue")` (then .removeClass to resort back to black, no need to explicitly have a different class for black)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in multiple ways, although it would be slightly variations from what you have used

Method 1 by using json structure in css method:

```
$("#tabel td").each(function() {
var cellValue = $(this).html();
if (!isNaN(parseFloat(cellValue))) {
    if (cellValue > 0) {
        $(this).css({'background-color': 'red'});
    }
    else if (cellValue == 0) {
        $(this).css({'background-color':'black'});
    }
  }
});
```

Method 2: Create two classes, add classes based on condition

```
$("#tabel td").each(function() {
    var cellValue = $(this).html();
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(cellValue))) {
        if (cellValue > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('redClass').removeClass('blackClass');
        }
        else if (cellValue == 0) {
            $(this).addClass('blackClass').removeClass('redClass');
        }
     }
});
```

Method 3: Create two class with following definition

```
.redClass {
     background-color: red;
}
.blackClass{
     background-color: black !important;
}
```

Note: add redClass by default within html itself, now simple toggle blackClass based on condition

```
$("#tabel td").each(function() {
    var cellValue = $(this).html();
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(cellValue))) {
        if (cellValue == 0) {
            $(this).toggleClass('blackClass');
        }
    }
});
```